# Sub-LightSpeed travel according to special relativity vs AP physics

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, observers

For background, I'm a high school physics Student, and I was recently looking at special relativity out of personal interest, and I read a summarized statement "**Time slows down as your approach the speed of light**" and so I went googling around and I saw an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240689/) like this on this stackexchange, and I've seen other answers which state things like "**Time only appears slow for the stationary observer**" and for me, this seems at odds with the basic idea of being able to see velocity.

Like take the example of a kid kicking the ball versus a railgun shot. Even if you were standing stationary, you would still see the speed difference. yet if the railgun shot was approaching 0.9999c or a similar value, it would appear slower?

Does one theory win over the other, or is my thinking flawed in some way? What Happens?

Comment: I get that I not may have a complete understanding of physics, but why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you.  I suspect your incorrect claims in the question are the cause.  If you are asking a question, best not to make such claims, although I understand that is a tricky judgement to make as a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements are mostly useless without context because they don't explicitly tell you what you can expect to measure. The natural language phrasing you want is:

**The clock which measures the shortest time between two events is the clock for which those two events are in the same place.**

And the formal statement you want is:

Given:

$\Delta t$ is the time measured by a clock in some frame of reference $A$ between two events in the same place

$\Delta t'$ is the time measured by a clock in some other frame of reference $B$ between those two events

$v$ is the velocity of $B$ with respect to $A$, hence the two events which are in the same place in the $A$ frame are are separated in space by $v \Delta t'$ in the $B$ frame

Then:

$\Delta t' = \dfrac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$

Observe that we reproduce the natural language statement: $\Delta t'$ (the time measured by a clock for which the events are not in the same place) is always bigger than $\Delta t$ (the time measured by a clock for which the events are in the same place) for all nonzero $v$, and the amount by which it is bigger increases with increasing $|v|$, with an infinite ratio in the limit as $|v| \to c$. It may be illustrative to plot the curve with the time ratio on the vertical axis and velocity on the horizontal axis to be able to visualize the relationship.